# iOS - Local Notifications independent from time zone

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I've got a problem with local notifications in iOS.
I want to schedule a notification at a certain time, but it must be fired regardless of the Time Zone... ie: if I schedule a notification at 03:00 PM it must fire at exactly at 03:00 PM wherever I am...
This is my code but I cannot achieve this result... could you help me?
Thank you!

```
static func createNotificationNamed(_ notificationName: String, at notificationDate: Foundation.Date, title: String, body: String, delta: UInt32) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
                var components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: notificationDate)
                components.minute = components.minute! + Int(arc4random_uniform(delta))

                var datecomp = DateComponents()
                datecomp.year = components.year
                datecomp.month = components.month
                datecomp.day = components.day
                datecomp.hour = components.hour
                datecomp.minute = components.minute
                datecomp.calendar = components.calendar
                datecomp.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: datecomp, repeats: false)
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = title
                content.body = body
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationName, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To simulate it I schedule the notification, then change the TimeZone on my phone and I wait for the right time, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function and pass your date and also give local notification permission on AppDelegate file, also check local permission iOS version wise.

```
func scheduleNotification(date: Date) {

    var dateComponents: DateComponents = DateComponents()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title =  // title
    content.subtitle =  // subtitle
    content.body =  // body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

    let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    let notiCurrent = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notiCurrent.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error1 = error {
            print(error1.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
You also declare the constant calendar but you never use it later.

Comment: I add my function that I used for local notification. Try it's.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've solved this issue setting the specific TimeZone...

```
datecomp.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "PDT")
```